# C# Nested Repeater not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been Looking around this for 3 days so please, any feed back will be appreciated . 
I have a parent repeater that pulls the expected data but i am trying to nest a child repeater, Find the Control and Populate the data. but so far it has not worked. For Some Reason the Nested Repeater Below Is Not Being picked Up to display The Proper Data.
Any Suggestions?

Asp.Net Code Is Here:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="EquipmentRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater2_ItemDataBound" > 
           <ItemTemplate>
                 <b>Equipment:</b>
               <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Equip") %>&nbsp;
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Location") %>&nbsp;
               </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>




protected void Repeater2_ItemDataBound(object sender System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater Repeater2 = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("EquipmentRepeater");

            System.Data.DataTable ds = new System.Data.DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(" Select HourID, Equip,Location FROM Equip where HourID=@id");

            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            con.Open();
            cmd1.Connection = con;
            cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            con.Close();
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            // DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            ad.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();


            //Need to assign the Data in datatable
            Repeater2.DataSource = ds;
            Repeater2.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your code tries to repopulate the same repeater. Where is your *nested* repeater?

Comment: If `EquipmentRepeater` is the nested Repeater, you are trying to bind data to it in it's own ItemDataBound event. You need to use the event of the parent Repeater.

Comment: You are Right, I changed the ItemDataBound to be on the Event Of the Parent Repeater, But It is Still NOT Populating the Data .It is More Like Finding The Child Repeater Control IS NOT working. Because I tried to Nest A GridView In the Parent Repeater but with No Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved It, There were 2 Problems:

1- The Repeater ItemDataBound Needed to be in the parent repeater Even Handler.
2-the second Problem was The Id Parameter Id for The Child repeater did Not have any value So Icreated a hidden filed In the Parent repeater for Id and called it on ItemDataBound

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="ID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />

 protected void Repeater2_ItemDataBound(object sender System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater Repeater2 = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("EquipmentRepeater");

        System.Data.DataTable ds = new System.Data.DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(" Select HourID, Equip,Location FROM Equip where HourID=@id");

          HiddenField id = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("ID");
            int parsedId = int.Parse(id.Value);
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = parsedId;
        con.Open();
        cmd1.Connection = con;
        cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        con.Close();
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        // DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();


        //Need to assign the Data in datatable
        Repeater2.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater2.DataBind();
    }

}
```

thank You all and good luck